# Convert row data to column data SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have gone through the existing solutions that are present and couldn't progress much.I have a table as below `#CompCodes`

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1eLm.png)

I want the data to be displayed as

```
ID Code1 Code1EffDate Code2 Code2EffDate
```

and so on till `Code15 Code15EffDate`

If it doesn't have value for any of the code and effdate it should be null

Currently I am using the below query which is not that accurate. for some ids it is giving me wrong values and some times it is duplicating the codes

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    pcc.[ID],
    pcd1.Code as Code1, pcd1.EffDate as EffDate1, 
    pcd1.CancelDate as CancelDate1, pcd1.ReasonCode as ReasonCode1,
    pcd2.Code as Code2, pcd2.EffDate as EffDate2,
    pcd2.CancelDate as CancelDate2, pcd2.ReasonCode as ReasonCode2,
    pcd3.Code as Code3, pcd3.EffDate as EffDate3,
    pcd3.CancelDate as CancelDate3, pcd3.ReasonCode as ReasonCode3,
    pcd4.Code as Code4, pcd4.EffDate as EffDate4,
    pcd4.CancelDate as CancelDate4, pcd4.ReasonCode as ReasonCode4,
    pcd5.Code as Code5, pcd5.EffDate as EffDate5,
    pcd5.CancelDate as CancelDate5, pcd5.ReasonCode as ReasonCode5,
    pcd6.Code as Code6, pcd6.EffDate as EffDate6,
    pcd6.CancelDate as CancelDate6, pcd6.ReasonCode as ReasonCode6,
   pcd7.Code as Code7,pcd7.EffDate as EffDate7,pcd7.CancelDate as CancelDate7,pcd7.ReasonCode as ReasonCode7,
   pcd8.Code as Code8,pcd8.EffDate as EffDate8,pcd8.CancelDate as CancelDate8,pcd8.ReasonCode as ReasonCode8,
   pcd9.Code as Code9,pcd9.EffDate as EffDate9,pcd9.CancelDate as CancelDate9,pcd9.ReasonCode as ReasonCode9,
   pcd10.Code as Code10,pcd10.EffDate as EffDate10,pcd10.CancelDate as CancelDate10,pcd10.ReasonCode as ReasonCode10,
   pcd11.Code as Code11,pcd11.EffDate as EffDate11,pcd11.CancelDate as CancelDate11,pcd11.ReasonCode as ReasonCode11,
   pcd12.Code as Code12,pcd12.EffDate as EffDate12,pcd12.CancelDate as CancelDate12,pcd12.ReasonCode as ReasonCode12,
   pcd13.Code as Code13,pcd13.EffDate as EffDate13,pcd13.CancelDate as CancelDate13,pcd13.ReasonCode as ReasonCode13,
   pcd14.Code as Code14,pcd14.EffDate as EffDate14,pcd14.CancelDate as CancelDate14,pcd14.ReasonCode as ReasonCode14,
   pcd15.Code as Code15,pcd15.EffDate as EffDate15,pcd15.CancelDate as CancelDate15,pcd15.ReasonCode as ReasonCode15,''
   FROM #CompCodes pcc
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd1 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd1.ProviderID AND pcd1.ColumnNumber=1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd2 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd2.ProviderID AND pcd2.ColumnNumber=2
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd3 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd3.ProviderID AND pcd3.ColumnNumber=3
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd4 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd4.ProviderID AND pcd4.ColumnNumber=4
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd5 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd5.ProviderID AND pcd5.ColumnNumber=5
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd6 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd6.ProviderID AND pcd6.ColumnNumber=6
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd7 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd7.ProviderID AND pcd7.ColumnNumber=7
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd8 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd8.ProviderID AND pcd8.ColumnNumber=8
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd9 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd9.ProviderID AND pcd9.ColumnNumber=9
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd10 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd10.ProviderID AND pcd10.ColumnNumber=10
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd11 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd11.ProviderID AND pcd11.ColumnNumber=11
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd12 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd12.ProviderID AND pcd12.ColumnNumber=12
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd13 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd13.ProviderID AND pcd13.ColumnNumber=13
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd14 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd14.ProviderID AND pcd14.ColumnNumber=14
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProvCompDetails pcd15 ON pcc.ProviderID=pcd15.ProviderID AND pcd15.ColumnNumber=15
   Order by pcc.ID
```

Can some one please help in writing this more efficiently?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is just a horribly bad design..... you should really first clean up your database design! The **first** normal form states there should be no repeating columns (like `Code1`, `Code2` etc.) - you should use a **proper, relational** design instead!

Comment: yes, I agree. but this is the existing system and currently being used by lot of people